# How to shorten CONDITIONS & ACTIONS of decision table in drools 5.5.0

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, business-rules, drools-planner

I am inserting an object "ABC" to knowledge session. This object contains a HashMap and that HashMap contains List of Objects of type "Person" and this "Person" contains HashMap to hold Person data such as Name,age,gender etc. Now as i have to read this Person in CONDITION to check age.

**abc: ABC()**

**CONDITION**
*abc.getUserMap().get("personList").getListOfPeople().getPeople().get("age")==$param*

**ACTION**
*"Action on parent object or Person Object"*

So here i want to reduce this CONDITION code to minimum.
For example
**CONDITION** - 
*xyz.getPeople().get("age")==$param*

**ACTION** - 
*xyz.getPeople().set($param) value = "Eligible"*

Comment: The expression accessing some person's age does not agree with the description of your data structure. -- If you want to simplify the conditions, simplify your objects. I cannot imagine a cogent reason for storing a Person's data in a Map containing a List of Person objects in preference to storing the Person objects as facts.

Comment: @laune this is a better way to declare nested objects or objects in Java. Advantages -1. No unnecessary setters and getters 2. Less code modification if one wish to change 3. Better time complexity.  I wrote the expression just to give an idea.

Answer (score -1):

On Class ABC you can create a Boolean method to eval the condition an check the result, Drools allow this. See [5.6. Function](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.M2/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e3373) section in Drools docs.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will check this and let you know if this works. This works with ACTION but i am not sure if we can use custom methods directly as u said in CONDITIONS too.